# i defined a bean in spring.xml and i want to use the bean in the java code by using @Autowired,but it fail

Tags: java, spring

this is a part of my spring.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wantao">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
<bean id="test1" class="com.wantao.bean.Student">
        <property name="studentId" value="161003530106"></property>
        <property name="studentName" value="万涛"></property>
        <property name="password" value="123"></property>
        <property name="sclass" value="德泰1613"></property>
    </bean>
```

this is my java code:

```
@Component
public class StudentDaoImplTest {
    @Autowired
    Student student;
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println(student);
    }
}
```

this is the result,and it was null.
[image]

Comment: How did you launch the test class?

Comment: use the junit to test,run with junit

Comment: You did not initiate the container... See this https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-spring-integration-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit doesn't recognize the Spring context by default. If you want to run JUnit and use Spring power, you need to use these annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    {"/path/to/spring.xml"})
public class StudentDaoImplTest {
    @Autowired
    Student student;
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println(student);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it just now ,it's right,thank you and the guy@Neng Liu